# org.json.JSONException: No value for email

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

while trying to access user details, I am getting this error:

```
07-29 14:49:47.343: W/System.err(2745): org.json.JSONException: No value for email
07-29 14:49:47.353: W/System.err(2745):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
07-29 14:49:47.374: W/System.err(2745):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
07-29 14:49:47.374: W/System.err(2745):     at com.example.healthcity.common.FacebookContainer$3$1.onCompleted(FacebookContainer.java:237)
07-29 14:49:47.409: W/System.err(2745):     at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:264)
07-29 14:49:47.413: W/System.err(2745):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1240)
07-29 14:49:47.423: W/System.err(2745):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-29 14:49:47.423: W/System.err(2745):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 14:49:47.433: W/System.err(2745):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 14:49:47.444: W/System.err(2745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-29 14:49:47.444: W/System.err(2745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 14:49:47.463: W/System.err(2745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 14:49:47.463: W/System.err(2745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-29 14:49:47.485: W/System.err(2745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-29 14:49:47.493: W/System.err(2745):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not able to capture breakpoint on callback method. plz help if you have gone through this error.

below is my code for getting user details:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    //RFR//_("onSessionStateChange----------------");
   /////////////// super.onSessionStateChange(state, exception);
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        readUserInfo(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        // Session closed
    }
}

private Request.GraphUserCallback graphCallback = new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

      // callback after Graph API response with user object
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
          String name = user.getName();
          String gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
          String email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
          String birthday = user.getBirthday();
          Log.d("FB----->","name: "+ name +" gender: "+ gender +" email: "+ email +" birthday: " +birthday);

      }

};

    public void readUserInfo(Session session){
        // make request to the /me API
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, graphCallback);
    }
```

And below is the permission that I've set:

```
openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email", "user_location"));
```

Here is the response i get from the graph api, when checked from browser:

```
{
  "id": "1000000XXXXX930",
  "name": "First Last",
  "first_name": "First",
  "last_name": "Last",
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/<myusername>",
  "username": "<myusername>",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

Comment: I have asimilar issue with this one using FacebookSDK 4.0. Do you solve this already?

Answer (score 4):

- **Exception is thrown because You are trying to access email**
- But user has not used email for registration and has used phone
  number for the registration.
- You have to check the possibility in code that whether the son
  response has the key and only then try to extract the value of that
  key

---

```
if(object.has("email")){
   userEmail = object.getString("email");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you given "email" permission to request the Facebook application to access any user's email id?

If you want to access email id of Facebook user using API then you must need to give email permission. General info about user profile will not give you the email address of the Facebook user.

[Email Permissions in Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)

**NOTE:** Some user also put security to do not share any email address to any other then also it might be the case that you will not get the email address.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes, i am testing with my account, and checked the permission on fb, they are set properly. however I've not made those details as public. may be this is an issue?

Comment: check the response first by log it and check does it contain any email field?

Comment: i've am already printing the details to log, see the onCompleted in the code. however i don't get it on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

you do need permission to grab someone's email although some people have their privacy set so that you can get their emails without this expressed permission, most don't.

Comment: i have set the permissions. see the lower part of question.

Answer (score 0):

This Piece of code is working fine with me in getting required permissions 
this will also help you in getting Email permission

```
  private void FaceBookSignIn()
   {
   facebookBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }

        if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
               Session.openActiveSession(SignIn_Rewards.this, false, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                      @Override
                      public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                              Exception exception) {

                          if (session.isOpened()) {

                              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                      new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                          @Override
                                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                                  Response response) {
                                              if (user != null) {

                                                  fromFB=true;

                                                 UserID=user.getId();
                                                 firstName=user.getFirstName();
                                                 Lastname=user.getLastName();
                                                 Gender=user.getProperty("gender").toString();
                                                 Email=user.getProperty("email").toString();
                                                 DateofBirth=user.getBirthday();
                                                try {
                                                    getToken();
                                                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                              }
                                          }
                                      });
                          }
                      }
                  });
              }
            // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

         else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
            // Ask for username and password
            OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) context);

            op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            op.setCallback(null);

            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("publish_stream");
            permissions.add("user_likes");
            permissions.add("email");
            permissions.add("user_birthday");
            op.setPermissions(permissions);

            Session session = new Session.Builder(SignIn_Rewards.this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForPublish(op);
        }




   }
  }) ;

      }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                  resultCode, data);

      Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
      if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
          Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
          Session.setActiveSession(session);
          currentSession = session;
      }

      if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
          Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              @Override
              public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                      Exception exception) {

                  if (session.isOpened()) {

                      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                              new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                          Response response) {
                                      if (user != null) {

                                          fromFB=true;

                                         UserID=user.getId();
                                         firstName=user.getFirstName();
                                         Lastname=user.getLastName();
                                         Gender=user.getProperty("gender").toString();
                                         Email=user.getProperty("email").toString();
                                         DateofBirth=user.getBirthday();
                                        try {
                                            getToken();
                                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have check like this:

```
private Request.GraphUserCallback graphCallback = new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

  // callback after Graph API response with user object
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
      String name = user.getName();
      String gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
      String email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
      String birthday = user.getBirthday();

     if(email!=null){
     //perform your task here.
     }else{
     Log.v("email","is empty");
     }

      Log.d("FB----->","name: "+ name +" gender: "+ gender +" email: "+ email +" birthday: " +birthday);

  }};
```

Comment: but its not a problem, what i get is a jsonexception not NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get value for email 
**Edited:** By default you won't get the email, for email you have to specify permission.

```
Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() 
        {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {
                if(session.isOpened())
                {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                        {

                            if(user != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Graph Inner Json"+user.getInnerJSONObject());
                                    String email = user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("email");
                                }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }

YourActivityName.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
```

This is our `openActiveSession()` where we specify permissions

```
private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback statusCallback)
    {
        OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity);
        openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email"));
        openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);

        Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();

        if(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI)
        {
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(openRequest);

            return session;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And in the End you should do in `onActivityResult` Method like:

```
if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```